# What is "UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-*" constraints? How to get rid of them?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

Layout error appeared while trying to get the landscape orientation. And layout becomes broken.

```
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
(Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, 
refer to the documentation for the UIView property
translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x78fc49c0 H:[UILayoutContainerView:0x78e536e0(320)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x799cf0e0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UILayoutContainerView:0x78e536e0(568)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x799cf0e0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UILayoutContainerView:0x78e536e0(568)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

And there is the similar error for vertical constraints.
I did not create those constraints. There are no UITabBar objects. I do not know which other objects create such constraints.